# Filtering a dict in Ansible

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

I have the following data that I have extracted from Ansible

```yaml
  neighbour_details:
    Port1:
    - host: SW1
      platform: Switch
    Port2:
    - host: RTR2
      platform: Router
    Port3:
    - host: SW3
      platform: Switch
```

```yaml
  trunk_ports:
  - Port1
  - Port3
```

I'm looking for a way to filter neighbour_details based on whatever that is on the trunk_port list to get the following output.

```yaml
  neighbour_filtered:
    Port1:
    - host: SW1
      platform: Switch
    Port3:
    - host: SW3
      platform: Switch
```

I've tried various ways and not able to get my head around how we do it in Ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        neighbour_filtered: "{{ dict(trunk_ports|zip(values)) }}"
      vars:
        values: "{{ trunk_ports|map('extract', neighbour_details)|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  neighbour_filtered:
    Port1:
      host: SW1
      platform: Switch
    Port3:
      host: SW3
      platform: Switch
```

---

If you want to keep the lists remove the filter *flatten*, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        neighbour_filtered: "{{ dict(trunk_ports|zip(values)) }}"
      vars:
        values: "{{ trunk_ports|map('extract', neighbour_details) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  neighbour_filtered:
    Port1:
    - host: SW1
      platform: Switch
    Port3:
    - host: SW3
      platform: Switch
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is missing Port1 and Port3 from the response.

Comment: You're welcome. To learn something more: See ``ansible-doc -t callback yaml`` The callback ``yaml`` makes the output YAML easier to read compared to default JSON. Set it in the config or use it per sessions ``shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook playbook.yml``